# Will the script work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Will this code work? I need to hide `h2` with `.hide` class after clicking `#idAnchor` link.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#idAnchor").click(function(){
    $(".hide").animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
});

});
</script>

<h2 class="hide">New users:</h2>

....

<div style="float: right; margin-top: 20px; ">
    <a href="#" id="idAnchor">More users</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try it? Of so, did it work?`

Comment: The "opacity" property has a **numeric** value.

Comment: So you got your answer.

Comment: only one way to find out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't behave as you expect because this line:

```
$(".hide").animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
```

Attempts to set the `opacity` to `"hide"`.

The [opacity CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity) must be a number between `0` and `1`. For example `0` if you want the element to be hidden.

```
$(".hide").animate({ opacity: 0 }, "slow");
```

If you actually want to take the element out of the flow, you probably want to touch the `display` property, which there is a short-hand for:

```
$(".hide").hide("slow");
```

Comment: can not start it work... the part of page which contains h2 is importing dynamicaly into the page, maybe this is the reason? but it's already imported before I click the link

Comment: Is the link also dynamically added to the page by any chance? If so you need to use a click event binding style that will cope with this: `$( "body" ).on( "click", "#idAnchor", function() {
  $(".hide").hide("slow");
});`

Comment: Can you supply an example that demonstrates the problem... here is an example that seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/dwcyvnLj/

Comment: thakns, the point is that the h2 also reloaded every time the link cliked :-) so the scriptis is OK, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make the changes in the below line:

```
$(".hide").animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
```

Change the opacity value like this:

```
$(".hide").animate({ opacity: '0.4' }, "slow");
```

After that it will work.

**Note:** Opacity's value always comes between 0 to 1. it may be in decimal like 0.4, 0.5 ... so on.

Comment: `opacity: 0`, not 1. You was the first, so then I can give you +1 :-)

Comment: @panther than for your positive response. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `event.preventDefault()` and `opacity` range is 0 to 1.

```
$("#idAnchor").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    $(".hide").animate({ opacity: 0 }, "slow");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just

```
 $(".hide").fadeTo("slow", 0);
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/8zorc40d/

Comment: can not start it work... the part of page which contains h2 is importing dynamicaly into the page, maybe this is the reason?

Comment: did you have jquery reference? and what version?